# Automated UnitTesting for several server/php versions on one machine

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, phpunit

How do I setup automated unittesting (I use phpUnit) for several PHP versions on the same server?
Or if not possible what affordable solutions are there?

I deploy my code to several customer servers with different setups.
So it would be a major benefit to be able to setup a server configuration according to the customer setup to test my code with.
But I can not afford to buy a machine per customer, nor would I have the space to put the machines ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can either install several PHP versions beside each other, or use a virtual machine for each customer.

## Multiple PHP versions on the same machine

I wrote [phpfarm](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpfarm/wiki/Home/) to achieve exact this goal: Run unittests for PEAR packages on many PHP versions.

It allows you to easily install many versions of PHP on your machine, set a default one, and gives you a PEAR/Pyrus installation for each of them. Installing extensions is also possible with that setup.

You can then run your unit tests with

```
$ php-5.3.23 /path/to/phpunit .
```

or

```
$ switch-phpfarm 5.2.23
$ phpunit .
$ switch-phpfarm 5.4.6
$ phpunit .
```

## Virtual machines

You may also use a virtual machine (e.g. via VirtualBox) per customer, which makes it easier to have the exact identical setup as your customer server.

When you've setup them, you may then automate them with e.g. [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).

Comment: Wow your phpfarm sound like it's exactly what I'm looking for, nice job! I'll give it a try :)